# Error with store_id for admin

Tags: magento-1.9, database

When I opened my site I had a

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Mage_Core_Model_Store::setWebsite() must be an instance of
>   Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given, called in
>   /var/www/hosts/mage-composer/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
>   on line 645 and defined in
>   /var/www/hosts/mage-composer/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php
>   on line 453 ( ! ) TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Mage_Core_Model_Store::setWebsite() must be an instance of
>   Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given, called in
>   /var/www/hosts/mage-composer/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
>   on line 645 in
>   /var/www/hosts/mage-composer/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php
>   on line 453

I opened my database and in `core_store` I saw [image]

but but the admin must have id = 0. I tried

```
update core_store
set `store_id` = 0
where `website_id` = 0
```

but it's id(ai), and I had error

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`usatravel`.`label_core_store`, CONSTRAINT `FK_LABEL_CORE_STORE_WEBSITE_ID_LABEL_CORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `label_core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CA)
```

how I can fix it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Don't forget to clear cache (delete all files in var/cache/* and var/session/*)